# Excluding entries which have equalled zero for a period of time

Tags: sql

I am looking for a way in SQL to discard values where Current Stock = 0 for a given time period.

Using the example below I would like to discard any entry from 08/01/23 if the entry from that date and so on have equalled zero:

[Image of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw97V.png)

---

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload table as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this using the "Gaps and Islands" problem. The trick is to start with a subquery that I call CTE_CONDITION which is basically filtering your data to any rows which meet your condition to search for "Islands".

The result of this query will give you a start and end date of any "Island" where your condition is met, as long as it overlaps on a buffer which in your case seems to be 1 month. So, any rows meeting your condition will be grouped into a single island, as long as the buffer of time is not exceeded.  If we go more than 1 month before seeing another 0, then it would treat that as a second island.

Therefore, this solution assumes you've already inserted the 0's in the correct place, as rows (it looks like you have).

I'm using Snowflake syntax here, so you might have to adjust the SQL to work in your specific RDBMS environment. Let's get started.

**Challenge 1: Calculate Islands**

```
WITH CTE_CONDITION AS (
  SELECT 
    Date_Col AS dtm, 
    Country, 
    Shop 
  FROM 
    YOURTABLE 
  WHERE 
    CURRENT_STOCK = 0 
    AND Date_Col is not null
), 
CTE_LAGGED AS (
  SELECT 
    dtm, 
    Country, 
    Shop, 
    LAG(dtm) OVER (
      PARTITION BY Country, 
      Shop 
      ORDER BY 
        dtm
    ) AS previous_datetime, 
    LEAD(dtm) OVER (
      PARTITION BY Country, 
      Shop 
      ORDER BY 
        dtm
    ) AS next_datetime, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY Country, 
      Shop 
      ORDER BY 
        CTE_CONDITION.dtm
    ) AS island_location 
  FROM 
    CTE_CONDITION
), 
CTE_ISLAND_START AS (
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY Country, 
      Shop 
      ORDER BY 
        dtm
    ) AS island_number, 
    Country, 
    Shop, 
    dtm AS island_start_datetime, 
    island_location AS island_start_location 
  FROM 
    CTE_LAGGED 
  WHERE 
    (
      DATEDIFF(MONTH, previous_datetime, dtm) > 1 
      OR CTE_LAGGED.previous_datetime IS NULL
    )
), 
CTE_ISLAND_END AS (
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY Country, 
      Shop 
      ORDER BY 
        dtm
    ) AS island_number, 
    Country, 
    Shop, 
    dtm AS island_end_datetime, 
    island_location AS island_end_location 
  FROM 
    CTE_LAGGED 
  WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, dtm, next_datetime) > 1 
    OR CTE_LAGGED.next_datetime IS NULL
) 
SELECT 
  CTE_ISLAND_START.Country, 
  CTE_ISLAND_START.Shop, 
  CTE_ISLAND_START.island_start_datetime, 
  CTE_ISLAND_END.island_end_datetime, 
  DATEDIFF(
    MONTH, CTE_ISLAND_START.island_start_datetime, 
    CTE_ISLAND_END.island_end_datetime
  ) AS ISLAND_DURATION_MONTH, 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
      CTE_LAGGED 
    WHERE 
      CTE_LAGGED.dtm BETWEEN CTE_ISLAND_START.island_start_datetime 
      AND CTE_ISLAND_END.island_end_datetime 
      AND CTE_LAGGED.Country = CTE_ISLAND_START.Country 
      AND CTE_LAGGED.Country = CTE_ISLAND_START.Country 
      AND CTE_LAGGED.Shop = CTE_ISLAND_START.Shop 
      AND CTE_LAGGED.Shop = CTE_ISLAND_START.Shop
  ) AS island_row_count 
FROM 
  CTE_ISLAND_START 
  INNER JOIN CTE_ISLAND_END ON CTE_ISLAND_END.island_number = CTE_ISLAND_START.island_number 
  AND CTE_ISLAND_START.Country = CTE_ISLAND_END.Country 
  AND CTE_ISLAND_START.Shop = CTE_ISLAND_END.Shop
```

The second CTE, `CTE_LAGGED`, uses the LAG and LEAD window functions to identify the previous and next dates for each country and shop. It also assigns a row number to each row, based on the date in `CTE_CONDITION`.

The third CTE, `CTE_ISLAND_START`, uses the row numbers and the `DATEDIFF` function to identify the start of each "island". An island starts when the previous date is more than one month before the current date, or when there is no previous date.

The fourth CTE, `CTE_ISLAND_END`, identifies the end of each "island". An island ends when the next date is more than one month after the current date, or when there is no next date.

Finally, the SELECT statement joins the `CTE_ISLAND_START` and `CTE_ISLAND_END` tables on the island number, country, and shop. It calculates the duration of each island in months and counts the number of rows within each island. The result is a table with columns for country, shop, island start date, island end date, island duration in months, and island row count.

This is a common problem, so I wrote a template in Rasgo that writes this SQL for you, if you wanted to change the columns, group by, or buffer size in the future. You can find that link [here](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=%22summarize_islands%22&tableState=%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22YOURTABLE%22%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Date_Col%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Country%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Shop%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Current_Stock%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22number%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Change%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22number%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22baseTableName%22%3A%22YOURTABLE%22%2C%22ddl%22%3A%22%22%7D&formState=%7B%22arguments%22%3A%7B%22group_cols%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22Country%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22Country%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A1%2C%22attributes%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A2%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22Shop%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22Shop%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A2%2C%22attributes%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%5D%7D%2C%22conditions%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22math_list%22%2C%22values%22%3A%5B%22CURRENT_STOCK%3D0%22%5D%7D%2C%22date_col%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column%22%2C%22col%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22Date_Col%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22Date_Col%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A0%2C%22attributes%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%2C%22buffer_date_part%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22date_part%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22MONTH%22%7D%2C%22buffer_size%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22int%22%2C%22value%22%3A1%7D%7D%2C%22transformName%22%3A%22summarize_islands%22%7D).

**Challenge #2 Excluding Rows within the Islands**

Now that you have that result, you simply join your data to that table with the condition that the date falls in between the Island Start and End Dates, for the same Country and Shop.

I won't repeat the SQL above, but you could wrap the whole thing in a CTE to make it easier to read and edit. Or, you could create a temporary table or something so that you can refer to it.

```
WITH CTE_ISLANDS_SUMMARY AS (
    {{ the whole sql above }}
)
SELECT A.*
FROM {{ YOURTABLE }} A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM CTE_ISLANDS_SUMMARY S
    WHERE S.SHOP = A.SHOP
    AND S.COUNTRY = A.COUNTRY
    AND S.ISLAND_START_DATETIME <= A.Date_Column
    AND S.ISLAND_END_DATETIME >= A.Date_Column
)
```

I prefer the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` style here, but you could also just do a LEFT OUTER JOIN and bring in the island ID or something from that table, which would give you a way to visualize the entire dataset and have the columns populated for where they exist in an island.

I hope that helps!